# Nextflow, Limit the number of concurrent workers in Google

Tags: nextflow

I was wondering if there is a way of limiting the number of concurrently running workers when using the Google Life Sciences executor.
I was using the following in my `nextflow.config` file, but apparently it did not matter.

```
executor {
    queueSize = 100
}
```

There were more than 100 workers concurrently running (the number in braces next to the processes name showed `108`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `executor.queueSize = 100` like you have done should exactly limit the number of parallel tasks the executor will handle. However, I think the problem you're hitting is actually due to this:

> The channel guarantees that items are delivered in the same order as
> they have been sent - but - since the process is executed in a
> parallel manner, there is no guarantee that they are processed in the
> same order as they are received.

This is true even when the queueSize is set to 1. The results might be unexpected, but we can test this pretty easily with:

Contents of `nextflow.config`:

```
executor {
    queueSize = 1
}
```

Contents of `main.nf`:

```
nextflow.enable.dsl=2

process test {

    tag { "myval: ${myval}" }

    input:
    val myval

    """
    sleep 1
    """
}

workflow {

    myvals = Channel.of( 'A'..'Z' )

    test( myvals )
}
```

Run with:

```
nextflow run -ansi-log false main.nf
```

Results:

```
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 21.04.3
Launching `main.nf` [ecstatic_visvesvaraya] - revision: d34a24fe4a
[b9/21ef9b] Submitted process > test (myval: B)
[39/783aaf] Submitted process > test (myval: H)
[b5/aeae8b] Submitted process > test (myval: A)
[7a/e36e72] Submitted process > test (myval: D)
[de/25f001] Submitted process > test (myval: I)
[72/f913f2] Submitted process > test (myval: C)
[43/a2c78e] Submitted process > test (myval: L)
[5b/7c0434] Submitted process > test (myval: F)
[25/884e7c] Submitted process > test (myval: E)
[16/4c3b41] Submitted process > test (myval: G)
[62/c7bee1] Submitted process > test (myval: Q)
[71/cdbd37] Submitted process > test (myval: J)
[e6/634461] Submitted process > test (myval: N)
[37/03dd88] Submitted process > test (myval: S)
[fd/70867c] Submitted process > test (myval: K)
[cf/fb7e83] Submitted process > test (myval: T)
[56/3d6d41] Submitted process > test (myval: M)
[1e/81ad89] Submitted process > test (myval: O)
[db/66a292] Submitted process > test (myval: R)
[d5/212940] Submitted process > test (myval: Z)
[a8/1a33ab] Submitted process > test (myval: P)
[7e/60daa7] Submitted process > test (myval: U)
[d5/4d19c4] Submitted process > test (myval: V)
[13/8404ff] Submitted process > test (myval: W)
[22/adb044] Submitted process > test (myval: X)
[65/21a22b] Submitted process > test (myval: Y)
```